# TYPEORM Update updated date column based on a specific column's update

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, sql-update, typeorm

I have added two columns, 'Paid Amount' and 'Paid Date' to an existing table (MySQL) in TypeORM (nodeJS).

Here, I want 'Paid Date' to update only when 'Paid Amount' column is updated.

Is it possible to define 'Paid Date' in the migration or model?

Below is my source code.

**migration.ts**

```js
export class addRefundCancellationFeesToReservationTables1644984542889 implements MigrationInterface {
    name = 'addRefundCancellationFeesToReservationTables1644984542889'

    public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query("ALTER TABLE `reservation` ADD `paid_amount` int DEFAULT NULL");
        await queryRunner.query("ALTER TABLE `reservation` ADD `paid_date` datetime(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)");
        ....
....}
```

**model.ts**

```js
.....
static readonly REFUND = 'paid_amount';
  @Column({ type: 'int', name: Reservation.PAID_AMOUNT, nullable: true })
  paidAmount: number | null;

  static readonly PAID_DATE = 'paid_date';
  @UpdateDateColumn({
    type: 'datetime',
    name: Reservation.PAID_DATE,
    precision: 3,
    default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)',
    onUpdate: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)',
  })
  .....
```